# Tns protocol adapter error with Oracle and ODAC

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g express edition.Getting error when I try to connect with

```
SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA
```

in command window.
Error is : TNS protocol adapter error.

```
tnsping tns_entry_name
```

Message:Used parameter files:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name

I am using window XP, Oracle Service is running, Firewall is off. 
I can connect through sqldeveloper but not through sql plus.

Please help guys, if you need any other information kindly reply.
Many thanks.

**EDIT**: tnsnames.ora file

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

**EDIT2** : Unistalled the Oracle Developer tools with ODAC 11.2 release 5. And everything goes back to normal. I can connect through sqlplus.
But I want to connect through .NET, Is ODTwithODAC 11.2r5 not compatible with oracle 11g express. Please help.

**EDIT3**: As by the comments, In order to use ODT with ODAC 11.2 , do I need to install Oracle Client also or there some another way. Please suggest Many thanks.

Comment: Check the tnsnames.ora file and compare the host and service names with the names you entered in sql developer.

Comment: @Jasti Its same ... I am using default XE for SID and service name both

Comment: Can you post screen shot of your sql developer connection and tnsnames.ora file

Comment: @Jasti Thanks for your swift reply. I doubt due to my reputation points I will not be allowed to post image, but I can post the text.

Comment: @Jasti I have just uninstalled the Oracle Developer Tools withODAC 11.2 release 5, and now I am able to connect through SQLPLUS. Do you know why is this happening. Is Oracle tool Dev not compatible with 11g express version. Thanks

Comment: Check your ORACLE_HOMEs

Comment: @OldProgrammer 11g express edition doesnt create HOME or is it? But ODTwithODAC do install under ORACLE HOME .Can you please explain in some detail many thanks

Comment: The only I can think of is it might have over written ORACLE HOME and other Environment variables.

Comment: @Jasti you are correct. But can you please tell where I could find or set HOME for 11g express . In enterprise edition it do made this.

Comment: @Jasti See edit3, do I also need oracle client then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sort out the problem by installing xcopy client,as express version doesnt have home path.
So I installed the Oracle Developer tools with xcopy client which I downloaded from : 
[HERE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html)

Its like Oracle 11g ODAC with Xcopy Deployment, which allows you to deploy the Oracle Instant Client and the ODP.Net driver just by copying a few DLLs over and registering them. That doesn't require a full-blown Oracle client installation.
Thanks @Jasti to put me into right direction through your valuable comments

Answer (score 3):

I suspect by installing Oracle Developer Tools you installed an oracle client next to your oracle database.
The windows PATH variable might have the bin directory listed of this client installation first instead of the database bin directory. This way you use that sqlplus instead of the one of your database. If this is the case you have to specify a correct connect identifier when trying to logon. eg.:

> sqlplus /@//localhost:1521/XE as sysdba;

or adjust the windows PATH to list the database bin first and restart your command prompt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I sort out the problem by installing xcopy client, as express version doesnt have home path. So I installed the Oracle Developer tools with xcopy client which I downloaded from : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html   Its like Oracle 11g ODAC with Xcopy Deployment, which allows you to deploy the Oracle Instant Client and the ODP.Net driver just by copying a few DLLs over and registering them. That doesn't require a full-blown Oracle client installation.

Answer (score -1):

The best thing someone can do is to go

> c:>\regedit ->SOFTWARE->Oracle->

change the `Oracle home/base` ..This is what I did to resolve my issue.